# How do I write a unit test when the system under test utilizes external static dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am creating unit test for my method

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateDisplayName(string displayname)
{
    bool status = _myProfileService.UpdateDisplayName(displayname, SessionAdapter.Instance._userDetailsViewModel.id);

    if (status)
        SessionAdapter.Instance._userDetailsViewModel.display_name = displayname;

    return Json(new { status = status, displayname = displayname }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and my test method is

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task UpdateDisplayName_Test()
{
    //Arrange
    var controller = new HomeController(userServiceMock.Object, myProfileServiceMock.Object);

    string displayName = "display";
    const string expected = "{ status = False, displayname = display }";
    myProfileServiceMock.Setup(m => m.UpdateDisplayName(It.IsAny<string>(), 1)).Returns(false);

    //var controllerContextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();

    //Act
    var result = await controller.UpdateDisplayName(displayName) as JsonResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result.Data.ToString());
}
```

My Session Info Class is below, this class i am using in session adapter

```
  public  class SessionInfo
    {
        public string Id { set; get; }
        public string Email { set; get; }
        public string UserName { set; get; }
        public UserDetailsViewModel _userDetailsViewModel { set; get; }
        public string permission { set; get; }

        //public string organization { set; get; }
        public OrganizationViewModels Organization { set; get; }
        public List<UserTeamModels> teams { set; get; }
        public string status { set; get; }
        public string role { set; get; }
        public List<string> roles { set; get; }
    }
```

I am unable to instantiate `SessionAdapter`. How can I unit test this?

My Interface and sessionadapter class were looks like below

```
public interface ISessionAdapterService
    {
        void Clear();
        void Abandon();
        bool DoesSessionExists { get; }
        SessionInfo Instance { get; set; } 
    }


    public class SessionAdapterService : ISessionAdapterService
    {
        private string sessionKey = "sessionInfoKey";

        public bool DoesSessionExists
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] == null ? false : true;
            }

        }

        public SessionInfo Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] == null ? null : (SessionInfo)HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey];
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] = value;
            }
        }



        public void Abandon()
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] = null;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();

        }
    }
```

My test case is same as the answer below

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task UpdateDisplayName_Test() {
    //Arrange
    var mySessionAdaptorService = new Mock<ISessionAdaptorService>();

    var controller = new HomeController(userServiceMock.Object, myProfileServiceMock.Object, mySessionAdaptorService.Object);

    var displayName = "display";
    var status = false;
    var id = 1;
    myProfileServiceMock.Setup(m => m.UpdateDisplayName(It.IsAny<string>(), id)).Returns(status);
    mySessionAdaptorService.Setup(m => m.Instance.Id).Returns(id);

    //Act
    var result = await controller.UpdateDisplayName(displayName) as JsonResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result); 
}
```

Code Update. Please find the below code i used for SessionAdapter class and ISessionAdapter Interface and also implementation.please give your suggestions is this correct way.

```
     public interface ISessionInfo
        {
            string Id { set; get; }
            string Email { set; get; }
            string UserName { set; get; }
            UserDetailsViewModel _userDetailsViewModel { set; get; }
            string permission { set; get; }

            OrganizationViewModels Organization { set; get; }
            List<UserTeamModels> teams { set; get; }
            string status { set; get; }
            string role { set; get; }
            List<string> roles { set; get; }
        }

        public  class SessionInfo : ISessionInfo
        {
            public string Id { set; get; }
            public string Email { set; get; }
            public string UserName { set; get; }
            public UserDetailsViewModel _userDetailsViewModel { set; get; }
            public string permission { set; get; }

            //public string organization { set; get; }
            public OrganizationViewModels Organization { set; get; }
            public List<UserTeamModels> teams { set; get; }
            public string status { set; get; }
            public string role { set; get; }
            public List<string> roles { set; get; }
        }

 public interface ISessionAdapter
    {
        void Clear();
        void Abandon();
        bool DoesSessionExists { get; }
        ISessionInfo Instance { get; set; }

    }


    public class SessionAdapter : ISessionAdapter
    {
        private string sessionKey = "sessionInfoKey";

        public bool DoesSessionExists
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] == null ? false : true;
            }
        }

        public ISessionInfo Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] == null ? null : (SessionInfo)HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey];
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] = value;
            }
        }

        public void Abandon()
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] = null;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();

        }
```

Comment: what is SessionAdapter?

Comment: session adapter is my static class with some properties and i m setting these details while login

Comment: Well you can't instantiate a static class. That's what static means.

Comment: Sounds like an external dependency you should be passing in to your controller constructor

Comment: can you please help me to write unit test for my method

Comment: yes i am using ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationSignInManager in constructor

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, you should *include that in your question*. You might be able to get away with initializing the properties of the SessionAdapter static class as part of the setup for your unit test. But really, it sounds like it's an external dependency and shouldn't be static - instead you should make it a non-static class and inject it as a dependency like you're doing with your user and profile services. That will allow you to mock it for your unit test. Writing testable code is important, and static classes don't lend themselves to testable code.

Comment: By the way, your `expected` string isn't valid JSON, and your action method will almost certainly produce valid JSON assuming it runs to completion. You'll need to fix that in order for your test to succeed.

Comment: @CharanTej abstract external dependency and inject it into the controller. As long as it remains static there isn't much else to do about it test-wise.

Comment: I am unable to write unit test for this .please some one help me on this

Answer (score 4):

Abstract external dependency and inject it into the controller. As long as it remains static there isn't much else to do about it test-wise

An abstraction can look like this

```
public interface ISessionAdapterService {
    int Id { get; }
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

with the following implementation.

```
public class SessionAdapterService : ISessionAdapterService {
    public string DisplayName { 
        get { return SessionAdapter.Instance._userDetailsViewModel.display_name; } 
        set { SessionAdapter.Instance._userDetailsViewModel.display_name = value; } 
    }

    public int Id {
        get { return SessionAdapter.Instance._userDetailsViewModel.id; }
    }
}
```

Controller would need to use abstraction as dependency

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateDisplayName(string displayname) {
    bool status = _myProfileService.UpdateDisplayName(displayname, sessionAdapterService.Id);

    if (status)
        sessionAdapterService.DisplayName = displayname;

    return Json(new { status = status, displayname = displayname }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Assuming `sessionAdapterService` is an injected `ISessionAdapterService`

The unit test can now mock the external dependency and inject it into the controller.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task UpdateDisplayName_Test() {
    //Arrange
    var mySessionAdaptorService = new Mock<ISessionAdaptorService>();

    var controller = new HomeController(userServiceMock.Object, myProfileServiceMock.Object, mySessionAdaptorService.Object);

    var displayName = "display";
    var status = false;
    var id = 1;
    myProfileServiceMock.Setup(m => m.UpdateDisplayName(It.IsAny<string>(), id)).Returns(status);
    mySessionAdaptorService.Setup(m => m.Id).Returns(id);

    //Act
    var result = await controller.UpdateDisplayName(displayName) as JsonResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    dynamic data = result.Data;
    Assert.IsNotNull(data);
    Assert.AreEqual(displayName, (string)data.displayname);
    Assert.AreEqual(status, (bool)data.status);
}
```

UPDATE.

based on your comments Updated abstraction of the SessionInfo class

```
public interface ISessionInfo {
    string Id { set; get; }
    string Email { set; get; }
    string UserName { set; get; }
    UserDetailsViewModel _userDetailsViewModel { set; get; }
    string permission { set; get; }

    OrganizationViewModels Organization { set; get; }
    List<UserTeamModels> teams { set; get; }
    string status { set; get; }
    string role { set; get; }
    List<string> roles { set; get; }
}

public class SessionInfo : ISessionInfo { ... }

public interface ISessionAdapterService {
    void Clear();
    void Abandon();
    bool DoesSessionExists { get; }
    ISessionInfo Instance { get; set; } 
}
```

I would also advise you to review you model design. It is very brittle and forces the session info class to be tightly coupled to implementation concerns.